# S3 put object with multipart uplaod

Tags: amazon-s3

I have tried all possible ways, can someone help me with S3 Put object synatx for multipart upload.

```
x <- rawConnection(raw(0), "w")
utils::write.csv(gene_read_counts, x)
put_object(rawConnectionValue(x), object = "xxx/data/processed/gene_read_counts_test2.csv", bucket = "dev-bkt")
put_object(file = gene_read_counts, object = "xxx/data/processed/gene_read_counts_test2.csv", bucket = "dev-bkt", headers = c('x-amz-server-side-encryption' = 'AES256'))
```

Error File size is 71984023. Consider setting 'multipart = TRUE'.Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : Forbidden (HTTP 403).

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear on what object are you trying to store.
Assuming you want to upload a large file to S3, use the following script.

```
import boto3

S3 = boto3.client('s3')

localFile = 'PATH/TO/LOCAL/FILE'
s3BucketName = 'MyS3Bucket'

S3.upload_file(localFile, s3BucketName, localFile)
```

This will automatically chunk your large file and upload it parallelly.

Comment: That makes sense but does it have any performance implications over classic multipart uploads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am running a r code on EC2 and one of the intermediate steps require writing a csv file to S3 bucket.The file size will be above 200 MB. O tried using put object but was failing due to argument object must be of type character. I think chunk upload is required i will try this.

Comment: Boto3 package is not available for R.  Cna you please suggest alternatives